# Issues using rest api body in powershell with Azure cli

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to az rest put command to enable one extension on my vm but have some issues with my body and don't know what should I try next or change. My syntax is probably wrong

These are my lines

```
 az rest --method put --uri https://management.azure.com/$resourceId/extensions/MDE.Windows?api-version=2015-06-15 --body { 
    "name": "MDE.Windows",
      "id": "$resourceId/extensions/MDE.Windows",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "location": "westeurope",
      "properties": {
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.AzureDefenderForServers",
        "type": "MDE.Windows",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
        "settings": {
            "azureResourceId": "$resourceId",
            "vNextEnabled": "true"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "defenderForEndpointOnboardingScript": "$defenderForEndpointOnboardingScript"
        }
      }
    }
```

This then outputs following

```
ParserError: "name": "MDE.Windows", Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.
```

i have tried --body with ' '

```
(Unsupported Media Type({"error":{"code":"UnsupportedMediaType","message":"The content media type '<null>' is not supported. Only 'application/json' is supported."}}))
```

and " "

but no luck.

```
(The command line is too long)
```

Any tips that I should try next or change in my code? Maybe try next something like this?

```
az rest --method put --uri https://management.azure.com/$resourceId/extensions/MDE.Windows?api-version=2015-06-15 --body @body.json
```

and just fyi: $defenderForEndpointOnboardingScrip is around 20 000 characters (one 'word').

Comment: Powershell doesn’t have syntax for writing json as a first class object - you’ll need to either declare a nested hashtable with *similar*-ish syntax (```@{ “key” = “value” }```) or put your json in a “here string”…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ParserError: "name": "MDE.Windows", Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.

I have reproduced in my environment by using below command and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest):

yy = name of the vm

```
az rest --method get --uri https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/$resourceId --body
@{
"name"="yy
}
```

[image]

Alternatively, I have reproduced in powershell in my environment the below example and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/manage-azure-resources-invoke-azrestmethod?view=azps-8.3.0#using-invoke-azrestmethod-with-get-operations):

xx-Name of the Resource group

```
 $getParams = @{    
 ResourceGroupName = 'xx'     
 Method = 'GET' }
```

Then I used below command:

```
Invoke-AzRestMethod @getParams
```

Then I get the below result:

[image]

So, you need to declare nested hash table like @{"x"="y"} like above example.
You can use powershell CMD `Invoke-AzRestMethod` with put method it works similarly as az rest method.